# failed to create error using ajax toolkit

Tags: ajax-toolkit

I'm using the ajax toolkit from within SF to create a custom object from a public page.
When I run this in sandbox everything works fine, but in production I get this error message.
To begin with I don't know why it says failed to create **account** as I'm not trying to create an account. 
More important, I cannot figure out why this fails in production (I checked the public profile and my custom object is createable and all it's fields are editable).

> failed to create account {errors:{fields:Content_Launch_SD__c,Subscribers_Number__c,Subscribers_Year_2__c,Project_Summary__c,Subscribers_Year_3__c,Hours_Catalog_HD_*c,DRM*_c,Subscribers_Year_1__c,User_Clients_Mobile_*c,Company*_c,IP_Channels_Tablet_*c,Territories*_c,Business_Model__c,Real_Time_*c,Revenue*_c,Time_Frame__c,Vendor_Time_Frame_*c,Streaming*_c,User_Clients_Tablet__c,Playout_Offline_Catalog__c,IP_Channels_Web__c,Content_Launch_HD__c,User_Clients_STB__c,CDN_Provider__c,CRM_Integration__c,User_Clients_Web__c,Free_to_Air_*c,Country*_c,Storage__c,Monthly_Content__c,Launch_Time_Frame__c,Billing_Provider__c,Hours_Catalog_SD_*c,Micropayments*_c,Subscription_*c,Content*_c,Lead_*c,Billing*_c,IP_Channels_STB__c,Distribution_Rights__c,IP_Channels_Mobile__c, message:'Qualification_Survey__c: bad field names on insert/update call: Content_Launch_SD__c, Subscribers_Number__c, Subscribers_Year_2__c, Project_Summary__c, Subscribers_Year_3__c, Hours_Catalog_HD_*c, DRM*_c, Subscribers_Year_1__c, User_Clients_Mobile_*c, Company*_c, IP_Channels_Tablet_*c, Territories*_c, Business_Model__c, Real_Time_*c, Revenue*_c, Time_Frame__c, Vendor_Time_Frame_*c, Streaming*_c, User_Clients_Tablet__c, Playout_Offline_Catalog__c, IP_Channels_Web__c, Content_Launch_HD__c, User_Clients_STB__c, CDN_Provider__c, CRM_Integration__c, User_Clients_Web__c, Free_to_Air_*c, Country*_c, Storage__c, Monthly_Content__c, Launch_Time_Frame__c, Billing_Provider__c, Hours_Catalog_SD_*c, Micropayments*_c, Subscription_*c, Content*_c, Lead_*c, Billing*_c, IP_Channels_STB__c, Distribution_Rights__c, IP_Channels_Mobile__c', statusCode:'INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE', }, id:null, success:'false', }

Comment: Can you post your code that's generating this error?

Comment: `INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE` Maybe you've forgotten to deploy some fields to the production?

Comment: Do you have a trigger on your object that is trying to create an account?

Comment: I think everything is deployed but I'll recheck.

Comment: I have no trigger that creates an account

Comment: I don't suspect its the code because it works fine in the sandbox